# How to display a multidimensional array under different sections in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I have been trying to create multidimensional arrays and display each array under each section .. but I keep ending up with a fatal error index out of range . The code that i display below is how I access my firebase data and print each array from the database.. issue is I get the data I assign an array to it create it but can’t seem to display it due to the error . Hope someone helps for reference regarding the error I have attached a screenshot as well.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!



var yourArray = [String]()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




  var sundaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var sundaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var sundaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var sundayfromarray = [String]()
var sundaytoarray = [String]()

var mondaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var mondaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var mondaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var mondayfromarray = [String]()
var mondaytoarray = [String]()

var tuesdaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var tuesdaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var tuesdaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var tuesdayfromarray = [String]()
var tuesdaytoarray = [String]()


var wednesdaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var wednesdaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var wednesdaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var wednesdayfromarray = [String]()
var wednesdaytoarray = [String]()


var thursdaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var thursdaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var thursdaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var thursdayfromarray = [String]()
var thursdaytoarray = [String]()


var fridaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var fridaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var fridaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var fridayfromarray = [String]()
var fridaytoarray = [String]()

var saturdaycoursenamearray = [String]()
var saturdaycoursecodearray = [String]()
var saturdaycourselocationarray = [String]()
var saturdayfromarray = [String]()
var saturdaytoarray = [String]()

var coursecodes = [[String]]()
var coursenames = [[String]]()
var courselocations = [[String]]()
var fromtimes = [[String]]()
var totimes = [[String]]()


 var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {




    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    if(uid == nil){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextviewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginscreen")
        //self.present(profileViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.present(nextviewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    for j in days {

    for i in 1 ..< 10 {

    let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("users").child((uid)!).child("courses").child(j).child(String(i))
          ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
           // print(dictionary)

            if j == "Sunday" {
            if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                self.sundaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                print(self.sundaycoursecodearray)

            }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.sundaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.sundaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.sundaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.sundaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.sundayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.sundayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.sundaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.sundaytoarray)

                }
            }

            if j == "Monday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.mondaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.mondaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.mondaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.mondaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.mondaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.mondaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.mondayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.mondayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.mondaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.mondaytoarray)

                }
            }

            if j == "Tuesday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.tuesdaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.tuesdaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.tuesdaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.tuesdaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.tuesdaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.tuesdaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.tuesdayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.tuesdayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.tuesdaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.tuesdaytoarray)

                }
            }

            if j == "Wednesday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.wednesdaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.wednesdaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.wednesdaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.wednesdaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.wednesdaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.wednesdaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.wednesdayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.wednesdayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.wednesdaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.wednesdaytoarray)

                }
            }

            if j == "Thursday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.thursdaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.thursdaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.thursdaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.thursdaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.thursdaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.thursdaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.thursdayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.thursdayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.thursdaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.thursdaytoarray)

                }
            }
            if j == "Friday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.fridaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.fridaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.fridaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.fridaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.fridaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.fridaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.fridayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.fridayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.fridaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.fridaytoarray)

                }
            }
            if j == "Saturday" {
                if let points = dictionary["coursname"] as? String {

                    self.saturdaycoursecodearray.append(points)
                    print(self.saturdaycoursecodearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["coursecode"] as? String {

                    self.saturdaycoursenamearray.append(points1)
                    print(self.saturdaycoursenamearray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["courseroomlocation"] as? String {

                    self.saturdaycourselocationarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.saturdaycourselocationarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["fromtime"] as? String {

                    self.saturdayfromarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.saturdayfromarray)

                }

                if let points1 = dictionary["totime"] as? String {

                    self.saturdaytoarray.append(points1)
                    print(self.saturdaytoarray)

                }
            }


            self.coursecodes.append(self.sundaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.mondaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.tuesdaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.wednesdaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.thursdaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.fridaycoursenamearray)
            self.coursecodes.append(self.saturdaycoursenamearray)


            self.coursenames.append(self.sundaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.mondaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.tuesdaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.wednesdaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.thursdaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.fridaycoursecodearray)
            self.coursenames.append(self.saturdaycoursecodearray)

            self.courselocations.append(self.sundaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.mondaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.tuesdaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.wednesdaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.thursdaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.fridaycourselocationarray)
            self.courselocations.append(self.saturdaycourselocationarray)

            self.fromtimes.append(self.sundayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.mondayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.tuesdayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.wednesdayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.thursdayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.fridayfromarray)
            self.fromtimes.append(self.saturdayfromarray)

            self.totimes.append(self.sundaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.mondaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.tuesdaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.wednesdaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.thursdaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.fridaytoarray)
            self.totimes.append(self.saturdaytoarray)


            self.tableview.reloadData()


        }
    })

        } }

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}





 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return days[section]
}

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return days.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return coursenames[section].count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! homeTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

  //  cell.classcode?.text = sundaycoursenamearray[indexPath.section]

    cell.classcode?.text = coursenames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
 // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return true
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if editingStyle == .delete {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
 } else if editingStyle == .insert {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
 // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return true
 }
 */

/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error is "Index out of range". I didn't check, but likely `days.count` != coursenames.count, so you can't do a `coursenames[i]` where i is < days.count but >= coursenames.count.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a model for your data then create arrays that include the model.

You can create a simple struct like so:

```
struct Course {
  var name : String?
  var code: String?
  var location: String?
  var toTime: String?
  var fromTime: String?
}
```

After you create the model you can create an array that contains this type of struct.

Also for numberOfRowsInSection you don't have to use subscript. Just return:

```
return coursenames.count
```

That is why you get the error.